# How to use Click event in dynamic groupbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I have a form like this. You can see my dynamic groupbox (30 groupbox) in Flowlayout on the right, and a picturebox to show questions on the left.
I'm worndering that How to use Click event for each groupbox to show the question equivalent in Picturebox?

Here's my code of groupbox

```
        public GroupBox gbx(String name, int s, string i, string msch)
    {
        this.Name = int.Parse(i);
        this.sda = s;
        this.MsCauHoi = msch;

        // gb
        // 
        if (s == 2)
        {
            gb.Controls.Add(cb1);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb2);

        }
        if (s == 3)
        {
            gb.Controls.Add(cb1);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb2);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb3);
        }
        if (s == 4)
        {
            gb.Controls.Add(cb1);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb2);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb3);
            gb.Controls.Add(cb4);
        }

        gb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, 44);
        gb.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gb.Name = name;
        gb.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 45);
        gb.TabIndex = 7;
        gb.TabStop = false;
        gb.Text = i;
        gb.BackColor = Color.Silver;


        // 
        // cb1
        // 
        cb1.AutoSize = true;
        cb1.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        cb1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 13);
        cb1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        cb1.Name = "cb1";
        cb1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 31);
        cb1.TabIndex = 0;
        cb1.Text = "1";
        cb1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cb1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        cb1.CheckedChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CheckBox b = new CheckBox();
            b = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (b.Checked == true)
            {
                gb.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;

            }
        };
        // 
        // cb2
        // 
        cb2.AutoSize = true;
        cb2.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        cb2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 13);
        cb2.Name = "cb2";
        cb2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 31);
        cb2.TabIndex = 1;
        cb2.Text = "2";
        cb2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cb2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        cb2.CheckedChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CheckBox b = new CheckBox();
            b = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (b.Checked == true)
            {
                gb.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;

            }
        };
        // 
        // cb3
        // 
        cb3.AutoSize = true;
        cb3.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        cb3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 13);
        cb3.Name = "cb3";
        cb3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 31);
        cb3.TabIndex = 2;
        cb3.Text = "3";
        cb3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cb3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        cb3.CheckedChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CheckBox b = new CheckBox();
            b = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (b.Checked == true)
            {
                gb.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;

            }

        };
        // 
        // cb4
        // 
        cb4.AutoSize = true;
        cb4.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        cb4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 13);
        cb4.Name = "cb4";
        cb4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 31);
        cb4.TabIndex = 3;
        cb4.Text = "4";
        cb4.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cb4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        cb4.CheckedChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CheckBox b = new CheckBox();
            b = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (b.Checked == true)
            {
                gb.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;

            }
        };
        return gb;
    }
```

And here's the code of FormLoad

```
       private void FrmThi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        droptable();
        this.CauDaLam = 0;
        if (dethi == null) setdethi();
        Screen scr = Screen.PrimaryScreen; //đi lấy màn hình chính
        this.Left = (scr.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2;
        this.Top = (scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in this.dethi.Rows)
        {
            String myValue = row["SoDA"].ToString();
            String msch = row["MaCH"].ToString();
            ptl = new FrmPhieuTraLoi();
            pn_DeThi.Controls.Add(ptl.gbx("cau" + (i + 1).ToString(), int.Parse(myValue), (i + 1).ToString(), msch));
            listptl.Add(ptl);
            i++;
        }
        loadcauhoi(this.CauDangLam);
        listptl[CauDangLam].setBackColorCDL();

        Random r = new Random();
        lbmade1.Text = r.Next(1, 4).ToString();
        txt = lbSatHachBangLai.Text;
        len = txt.Length;
        lbSatHachBangLai.Text = "";
        timer1.Start();
        this.timer2.Start();

    }
```

Comment: Since this is winforms - Assuming you have a DataStructure holding the list of questions. Assuming the DataStructure is Indexed. Create one Event Handler for the GrpBox click event - and when you dynamically create the groupbox, assign the event to it. Also set the Tag property of the groupBox to be the Index of the question. This way on Click event firing - using the (sender as GroupBox).Tag => you can find the question

Comment: Could you please give me more detail? How to create Event Handler for the GrpBox click event

Answer (score 2):

This is an example code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
    {
        var gBox = new GroupBox();
        gBox.Height = 50;
        gBox.Width = 50;
        gBox.Text = "Box: " + idx;
        gBox.Tag = idx;

        gBox.MouseClick += GBox_MouseClick;

        this.Controls.Add(gBox);
    }
}

private void GBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //var ctrl = sender as Control; -- Not required
    int questionIdx = (int)(sender as Control).Tag;            
}
```

Comment: I followed your instruction. But i encounted this error
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
here is my code:
       `private void Gbox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var ctrl = sender as Control;
            int questionID = (int)(sender as Control).Tag;
            loadcauhoi(this.CauDangLam);

        }`

And in FormLoad:

              `ptl.getGroupBox().MouseClick += Gbox_MouseClick;`

Comment: @PhucCoi - Do you get exception in loadcauhoi() method call. Check this.CauDangLam <--- May be Null. In Visual Studio you can Debug the code and find which line throws exception and what object is null.

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the GroupBox control and add a property for the Question ID (Add new Item > Custom Control) and change the class to look like this:

```
    public partial class QuestionGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        public string QuestionID;

        public QuestionGroupBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
```

Then populate your flowlayout and set the QuestionID and Click EventHandler, similar to this:

```
 var gb = new QuestionGroupBox{  QuestionID = "44"};
 gb.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.questionGroupBox_Click);
 //add add to your flow layout
```

Finally create your event handler to get and display the question

```
private void questionGroupBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var questionID = ((QuestionGroupBox)sender).QuestionID;
   //display your question
}
```

Comment: You could do the same thing without extending GroupBox and use the Tag property as Prateek suggested (it's a bit of a hack, but it makes easier)

Comment: This is more maintainable, extendable, safe and clearer to understand

Comment: I followed your instruction. But i encounted this error
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
here is my code:
       `private void Gbox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var ctrl = sender as Control;
            int questionID = (int)(sender as Control).Tag;
            loadcauhoi(this.CauDangLam);

        }`

And in FormLoad:

              `ptl.getGroupBox().MouseClick += Gbox_MouseClick;`

Comment: Sorry - that is not enough information, you will have to debug and figure it out.